# Como personalizar páginas de erro no cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-2

Como criar páginas de erro personalizadas no cakePHP?

Comment: Por que ampla demais, pessoal? Dá pra responder isso sim. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#exception-renderer

Comment: basta editar o arquivo `app/View/Errors/error500.ctp`

Comment: Eu editei esse arquivo e nada aconteceu. Eu queria criar uma tela pra cada erro, uma pro 403, 404, 405. ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda, encontrei a resposta no link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#exception-renderer

É só criar View/Erros/ e criar views com nomes correspondentes ao erros tipo: error404.ctp, fatal_error.ctp e editar os arquivos de uma maneira que os atende. Versão 2.5.7.